# reading linux kernel source code

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

Is there a tool that helps in reading the linux kernel source code? I'm using linux most of time but is there a tool that makes it easier to navigate through the functions of the kernel? Perhaps something like a debugger but it meant only for jumping to functions through the kernel?

Comment: This is what I use: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try some [source navigator](http://sourcenav.berlios.de/), or use [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) (or `etags` with `emacs`), or [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) etc...

You could consider also [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/).

You could extend the GCC compiler, e.g. using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), to suit your needs.

Most importantly, read some good books and tutorials about the kernel internals. Ask also on [kernelnewbies.org](http://kernelnewbies.org/)

Comment: This one looks interesting cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful and convenient resource for this goals:

[Elixir.bootlin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) links you to the declarations, definitions and instances of kernel symbols (functions, types, data, structures).

For example: [platform_get_irq()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/platform_get_irq), [GFP_KERNEL](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/GFP_KERNEL), [file_operations](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/file_operations) or you can see whole source file that contains clickable symbols [fb.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fb.h).